# What random variable does this converge to?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Say I have a sequence of IID random variables $(U_n)_{n \geq 1}$ which are uniform are $[0, 1]$ and $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ where:

$$X_0 = p \in (0, 1)$$
$$X_{n + 1} = \theta X_n + (1 - \theta)I_{[0, X_n]}(U_{n + 1})$$

where $\theta \in (0, 1)$ and $I$ is the indicator function. I've already proved that: (a) this is a martingale; and (b) $X_n \to L$ in any $\mathcal{L}^p$. But, I can't figure out what $L$ is. Can anyone help?

P.S. this is a practice question for an exam I have tomorrow, not homework.

Comment: It should be clear that $X_n$ converges to zero. Consider that $\theta X_n< X_n$.

Comment: @Math1000 well, yeah, but if $X_n > 1/2$ then $X_{n + 1}$ is more likely to grow than shrink, right? So, it seems like maybe the answer is: $L = \delta_0$ if $p < 1/2$ and $L = \delta_1$ if $p > 1/2$? And, I guess, $L$ can be $0$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$ each if $p = 1/2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty clear that $P(L \in \{0,1\}) = 1$ because those are the only fixed points of the recurrence relation for $(X_n)$.  Now, we know that $\mathbb{E}[L] = \lim \mathbb{E}[X_n]$ because $(X_n) \rightarrow L$ in $L^1$, and because $(X_n)$ is a martingale we know $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = X_0 = p$.  Hence $p = \mathbb{E}[L] = P(L=1)$.  So $L$ is a random variable with distribution $P(L=1)=p$, $P(L=0)=1-p$.

Comment: Thanks! Most of this makes sense to me. One question though - why does L have to go to fixed points with probability 1?

Comment: Whenever you have a relation like $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$, if it converges, the limit must satisfy $x = f(x)$, basically just by taking limits on both sides.